# Python - Selenium webdriver raises "\n" in exception while obtaining webdriver instance

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I recently encountered this issue while using Selenium webdriver.

When I try to obtain an Edge webdriver instance, it raises an exception, but the exception message only includes "\n", which gives me no clue on what actually happened. I've tried to Google this exception and gone through the possible list of exceptions of Selenium but got no luck.

Versions of my Edge and Edge driver are the same:

```sh
$ /Applications/Microsoft\ Edge.app/Contents/MacOS/Microsoft\ Edge --version
Microsoft Edge 97.0.1072.55
$ /Users/zhongdongy/Libs/msedgedriver --version
MSEdgeDriver 97.0.1072.55 (ce3bf3364880558d4945082f4ac36e01fe36716e)
```

Selenium version: `4.1.0`

Operating system info (macOS Big Sur 11.6 Apple Silicon):

```sh
$ uname -a
Darwin 192.168.0.104 20.6.0 Darwin Kernel Version 20.6.0: Mon Aug 30 06:12:20 PDT 2021; root:xnu-7195.141.6~3/RELEASE_ARM64_T8101 arm64
$ python3 --version                                                         
Python 3.10.0
```

Here is the code example:

```py
from selenium.webdriver import Edge

try:
    exec_path = "/Users/zhongdongy/Libs/msedgedriver"
    driver = Edge(exec_path)
    print(driver)
    driver.get('https://bing.com')
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    exit(1)
```

And a screenshot of the exception using PyCharm debugger:

[PyCharm debugger screenshot][1]

Thanks in advance!

[1] https://i.stack.imgur.com/NeWIM.png

Comment: I do notice that the Microsoft Edge app binary has two architectures (`x86_64` + `arm64`), but Edge web driver only has one architecture (`x86_64`), could this be the reason? And if so, is there a workaround?

```
Edge browser:
Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
Mach-O 64-bit executable arm64

Edge webdriver:
Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using chrome driver

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Users\\Swaminath\\Downloads\\chromedriver.exe")
header=[] #List to store name of the product
driver.get("https://news.google.com/?hl=en-IN&gl=IN&ceid=IN:en")
content = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
#print(soup)
for a in soup.findAll('a',href=True, attrs={'class':'FVeGwb CVnAc'}):
    newheaders=a.find('div', attrs={'class':'lBwEZb BL5WZb xP6mwf'})
    print(newheaders.text)    
    try:
        header.append( newheaders.text)       
    except:
        None
df = pd.DataFrame({'Header':header}) 
df.to_csv('News.csv', index=False, encoding='utf-8')
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but unfortunately, all chromium based browsers (stable, beta, dev, canary channels) failed in my case, even Safari (which doesn't require additional web drivers to be installed). And my code works just fine on Linux systems (I don't have Windows machine to test).